# Singleton design in PHP

Tags: php

I am using the singleton design pattern in a PHP application to create a database connection and select the database. I am using this instance many times in the application for CRUD operations.

Is there any problem if my application is accessing the database on multiple threads, such as getting unreliable results?

Is the created instance per session or for all threads?

Comment: PHP is not multithreaded. Oh and singletons are evil ;-)

Comment: Singletons have no use in PHP.

Comment: @NikiC I use them frequently to avoid `$_GLOBALS`.

Comment: @NikiC You must have never used Zend.

Comment: @Ross @Daniel Correcting myself, Singletons have no use in *good* PHP code. Singletons are introducing global state. That's `global $var`, just with a fancy name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no threads in PHP. Each request start from scratch; objects and resources are not shared.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you have some weird frankenstein setup, all request processed by php are independent and do not share anything.
Therefore, the singleton instance is per request (I think that's what you're calling thread).

So you should not have to worry about user A receiving something that was intended for user B.

Comment: +1 for frankenstein awareness (though the no-threads answers are correct)

Comment: if singleton instance is per request,why we are create.pls tell me

Comment: @user1021904 To avoid having, e.g., 2 database connections for one request.

Comment: @rdlowrey Thanks, you never know what people use APC and friends for ;).

Answer (score 3):

PHP is single threaded.  Each time a PHP script is executed it starts from scratch.  Objects you create in the script are created anew every time.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldnt be any problems with multithreading because PHP isnt multithreaded.

Comment: He did not ask how to implement a singleton.

Comment: And i didnt explain how to implement a Singleton, the article explains an issue regarding Multithreaded Singleton, which i found interessting for the OP.

Comment: The article is called "Implementing Singleton in C#" and, i.a., explains multithreaded singletons using functionality (lock et al.) that php does not even have. Other than the words 'singleton' and 'thread' this does not have anything to do with the OP's problem.

Comment: well it depends if the OP knows C# or no, because the issue of multithreading and singleton is well disscussed in the article, but i guess your right, this doesnt belong here. I'll delete ethe Link.